# Speed up numpy integer-array indexing for depth

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have an array

```
 [[0 2 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [2 1 1]]
```

and I want to convert it into a tensor of the form

```
[[[1 0 0]
  [0 1 0]
  [0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [0 1 1]]
 [[0 1 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [1 0 0]]]
```

Where each depth layer (index `i`) is a binary mask showing where `i` appears in the input.

I have written code for this which works correctly but is too slow for any use. Can I replace the loop in this function with another vectorized operation?

```python
def im2segmap(im, depth):
    tensor = np.zeros((im.shape[0], im.shape[1], num_classes))

    for c in range(depth):
        rows, cols = np.argwhere(im==c).T
        tensor[c, rows, cols] = 1

    return tensor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a==np.arange(num_classes)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
```

Or with `builtin` outer comparison -

```
(np.equal.outer(range(num_classes),a)).astype(int)
```

Use `uint8` if you have to use an `int` dtype or keep as `boolean` by skipping the `int` conversion altogether for further boost.

Sample run -

```
In [42]: a = np.array([[0,2,1],[1,0,1],[2,1,1]])

In [43]: num_classes = 3 # or depth

In [44]: (a==np.arange(num_classes)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
Out[44]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```

To have the `depth/num_classes` as the third dim, extend the input array and then compare against the range array -

```
(a[...,None]==np.arange(num_classes)).astype(int)
(np.equal.outer(im, range(num_classes))).astype(int)
(np.equal.outer(im, range(num_classes))).astype(np.uint8) # lower prec
```

Comment: This is really cool. How can this be edited to output the depth as the third dimension? (x,y,depth) instead of (depth,x,y). I tried a couple of things but it did not broadcast.

Comment: @RabeezRiaz It would be : `a[...,None]==np.arange(num_classes)` then.